# How to make sitemap for unfriendly URL's.

Tags: xml, sitemap

My site is like a search engine, something like this:

```
example.com
example.com/result/index.php?tag1=xyz&tag2=Empty
```

But, if i use non-friendly url's like `?tag1=xyz&tag2=Empty`

I get this error in Sitemap xml file

```
error on line 12 at column 83: EntityRef: expecting ';
```

Here is my code
`

```
<url>
  <loc>http://example.com/</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://example.com/result/index.php?tag1=abc&tag2=Empty/</loc>
</url>
<url>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try This.. ( Use `<![CDATA[ ......   ]]>` )

```
<url>
  <loc>http://example.com/</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc><![CDATA[http://example.com/result/index.php?tag1=abc&tag2=Empty/]]></loc>
</url>
<url>
```

**OR**  ( Replace `&` with `&amp;` )

```
<url>
  <loc>http://example.com/</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc> http://example.com/result/index.php?tag1=abc&amp;tag2=Empty </loc>
</url>
<url>
```